# SSH not able to remember password

Tags: mercurial, phpstorm, openssh

I'm using PHPStorm and an "OpenSSH" dialog continues to pop up every few minutes on a project I'm working on.  It appears to be trying to fetch a status from the remote Mercurial repository.  How can I configure OpenSSH to remember my password?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OpenSSH will bravely refuse to save passwords.  You need to setup a public key, run the key agent, and then add that key.  Here's a howto: http://paulkeck.com/ssh/

Comment: You're right, however in this case a simpler solution was for me to turn off the "Check for incoming/outgoing changesets" in the Mercurial plugin configuration.